# RelayCommand CanExecute not working when parameter passed with async lambda

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following command which works:

```cs
private ICommand _AddNewCommand;
public ICommand AddNewCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_AddNewCommand == null)
        {
            _AddNewCommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
                                              {
                                                  await AddNewAsync();
                                              }, AddNewCommand_CanExecute);
        }
        return _AddNewCommand;
    }
}
```

The button bound to this is correctly enabled/disabled according to the `AddNewCommand_CanExecute` method result.

However, if I want to pass some parameter into my `AddNewAsync()` method I do this:

```cs
 _AddNewCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(async obj =>
                                          {
                                              await AddNewAsync(obj);
                                          }, AddNewCommand_CanExecute());
```

Note that `AddNewCommand_CanExecute` has to be changed to `AddNewCommand_CanExecute()`.

However, when I do this, the bound button is always enabled even though `AddNewCommand_CanExecute()` should be returning false (given that it hasn't changed between the two).

What's going on here?

Comment: Please, share the rest of code, `AddNewCommand_CanExecute()` and `RelayCommand` implementation

Comment: I've added the rest of the `RelayCommand`. I haven't added the `CanExecute` code because it's simply a method (`public bool AddNewCommand_CanExecute() { }`) with a whole bunch of logic not relevant to the question because it works when not passing a parameter into the command, so the problem isn't there.

Comment: @WSC: You forgot to tell us how the `RelayCommand<T>´ class is implemented. This is what primarily matters.

Comment: `RelayCommand` is from `Galasoft.Mvvmlight.CommandWpf` (https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommand.cs).

Comment: @WSC: Then you are using the wrong overload. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the overload of `RelayCommand<T>` that accepts a `keepTargetAlive` parameter of type `bool`.

You should use the one that accepts a `Func<T, bool>` predicate:

```
_AddNewCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(async obj =>
{
    await AddNewAsync(obj);
}, _ => AddNewCommand_CanExecute());
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realise `_ =>` completely changed the overload it was using. I thought because I was passing in an object and bool I was in fact using `Func<T, bool>`.